# Nested Resources Routing with Plain-Ruby-Object Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested, activemodel

Having:

```
class User < WsBasedPlainRubyObject
  def subscriptions
     Subscription.where(:user_id=>self.id)
  end

  [...]
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_user #using an underlying composed_of
  [...]
end

resources :users do
  resources :subscriptions
end
```

When I try to use the helper method `user_subscriptions_path(@current_user)` on the view, `params[:user_id]` content contains the user's serialization instead of its id.

Is there any practical way to avoid this, maybe by using ActiveModel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `user_subscriptions_path(@current_user.id)` works fine..

Anyway, here goes a nice writeup on how to make Ruby objects behave like ActiveRecord Objects by using ActiveModel: 
[ActiveModel: Make Any Ruby Object Feel Like ActiveRecord](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/)